# Is a new domain registration available at the exact same moment for everybody?

Tags: dns, tld

I am wondering whether a new domain registration will become available at the exact same moment for everybody?

Because a new domain registration will not have DNS records set up already; I assume no caching will occur. Thus one would think that globally the domain's DNS records will become available at the exact same moment.

However I could not find any definite answer to my question; and would like to know for sure whether my theory mentioned above is correct.

Hoping somebody can tell me for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> at the exact same moment for everybody?

Yes and no. At the exact same moment for all **registrars** in most cases yes.

But you are not saying which TLD you are working with, and this makes a huge difference.

First not all TLDs are using registrars. Second some TLDs are using specific measures for domains about to be deleted and released to the "public", like pre-ordering list or specific catch-up servers to which the registrars need to connect, etc.

> Because a new domain registration will not have DNS records set up already; I assume no caching will occur.

This is not clear. A domain name not existing is also something put in cache, it is an `NXDOMAIN` return code and is put in cache in resolvers for a period up to the `negative TTL` which is an element present in the `SOA` field of the parent (TLD).
This is in fact a cause of major problems as some people do test, see the domain does not exist, then register it and then do not understand why they do not see it "immediately".  Others may see it immediately, but they may not because they "polluted" the cache of the recursive DNS server they are using.

> globally the domain's DNS records will become available

Hence no, for the reasons above: various caches around the world may have cached the NXDOMAIN reply.

I think you are confusing registration with publication. A name can be registered but not published at all. It is also registered at time T but can only be seen somes times later depending on the various caches' content.

Comment: You should also mention 'sun-rise' periods and 'reserved' names especially if its for a new top level zone as there are implications if the OP is not the 'owner' of other matching domains in some cases.

Comment: @user3788685 there are indeed many edge cases but I do not feel about doing something too generic where having the TLD could have targeted the discussion to the specific cases we are at, which I believe from experience and "tone" of the question is more about drop catching expiring domain names in a gTLD. If I am wrong the OP will need to update his question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the domain is available for registration until any of domain registrar has confirmed the purchase to the IANA (Internet Assigned numbers authority). 
So you can kinda relate it with a transaction lock at the database level, while making the purchase, until than its available for everyone to purchase.

Comment: No, IANA has no role in domain name registrations.